# Dúvida Mysql comparar várias colunas

Tags: php, mysql

Boa Noite,

Estou com um projeto onde preciso compara qual funcionário atende determinados requisito, a estrutura do banco esta assim:

[image: Estrutura do Banco]

Tenho uma tabela com a pontuação requisitada para cada cargo e em cada requisito, queria saber se tem tem como eu listar apenas os funcionários que estão dentro desse padrão, no caso da imagem da estrutura, apenas o José atende os requisitos, queria algo que listasse ordenando dos que atendem aos que menos atendem, acho que no PHP eu consigo fazer essa manipulação, queria saber se tem como fazer essa Query ja direto no banco. Obrigado!

Comment: apenas o José atende os requisitos, que avaliação é essa?

Comment: Se você comparar na Tabela Pontuação, o José é o Codigo 1, ele tem respectivamente 67, 56, 76 nos requisitos 1,2,3. O exigido pelo cargo do José conforme na Tabela Padrão Cargo é 40, 48, 69 respectivamente nos requisitos 1,2,3. então o José tem alem do exigido pelo cargo, no caso do João, codigo 2 na Tabela Pontuação..ele não atende no requisito 2, pois tem 34 e o exigido na tabela Padrão Cargos é 48.

Comment: agora deu pra entender

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### tl;dr

Este é um caso que se resolve bem com `JOIN`, afinal todas as tabelas tem uma estrutura muito regular, e uma relação bem direta:

```
SELECT    nome,
          COUNT(*) AS atendidas,
          SUM(pontuacao.valor - padraocargo.valor) AS excedente

FROM      funcionario
          JOIN pontuacao ON codigo = codfunc
          JOIN padraocargo USING(requisito)

WHERE     pontuacao.valor >= padraocargo.valor

GROUP BY  codigo

ORDER BY  COUNT(*) DESC,
          SUM(pontuacao.valor - padraocargo.valor) DESC
;
```

Saída:

```
nome  atendidas  excedente
JOSÉ          3         42
JOÃO          2         55
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49868e/1)**.

(no final da resposta tem uma versão que contabiliza o excedente de outra maneira)

### Entendendo:

Antes de mais nada, temos que relacionar as tabelas:

```
JOIN pontuacao ON codigo = codfunc
JOIN padraocargo USING(requisito)
```

No caso da `pontuacao`, queremos a pontuação específica de cada funcionário, e os campos tem nomes diferentes, então usamos `ON`. No caso do `requisito`, como o campo é igual tanto na pontuação quanto no `padraocargo`, podemos optar por `USING()`.

Até então, veja nosso `JOIN` funcionando: ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/059485/4))

```
nome  pontuacao  desejado
JOSÉ         67        40
JOSÉ         56        48
JOSÉ         76        69
JOÃO         56        40
JOÃO         87        48
JOÃO         34        69
```

Como buscamos os casos onde a pontuação supera o padrão, usamos esta condição:

```
WHERE pontuacao.valor >= padraocargo.valor
```

Resultando em:

```
nome  pontuacao  desejado
JOSÉ         67        40
JOSÉ         56        48
JOSÉ         76        69
JOÃO         56        40
JOÃO         87        48
```

Mas nós não queremos comparar linha a linha. Queremos saber quem é mais qualificado apenas, então fazemos um agrupamento por funcionário:

```
GROUP BY  codigo
```

O campo `codigo` é o ID do funcionário, por isto usamos como critério. Isto esconderá as linhas, então precisamos retornar de outra forma:

```
SELECT    nome,
          COUNT(*) AS atendidas
```

E para ajudar na leitura, classificamos começando pelo mais pontuado:

```
ORDER BY  COUNT(*) DESC
```

Ok, resolvemos o que foi pedido na pergunta. Mas pode acontecer de haver um "empate", no sentido de mais de  um dos funcionários atender ao requisito. Para melhorar a classificação, podemos retornar os pontos excedentes desta maneira:

```
SUM(pontuacao.valor - padraocargo.valor) AS excedente
```

E, é claro, ordenar como segundo critério:

```
ORDER BY  COUNT(*) DESC,
          SUM(pontuacao.valor - padraocargo.valor) DESC
```

Note que o excedente é das que ele passou. Tem uma saída interessante se quiser saber o excedente geral. Não vou detalhar muito para não confundir, mas em resumo é só:

- Tirar a condição `WHERE`
- Trocar `COUNT(*) AS atendidas por SUM(IF(pontuacao.valor >= padraocargo.valor,1,0)) AS atendidas`

Desta forma, o excedente contabilizará o que não foi atendido também. ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/059485/5))

Se quiser retornar apenas os funcionários que passarem por todos os critérios, pode fazer assim:

- Tirar a ordenação por `atendidas`, já que só serão exibidas as completas
- Acrescentar um `HAVING COUNT(*) = 3`

Ok, mas e se cada cargo tiver quantidades diferentes de requisitos?

- Faça uma query antes para obter o valor:

  ```
  SELECT @numreq = COUNT(*) FROM padraocargo WHERE cargo = (id do cargo);
  ```
- Acrescente um `HAVING COUNT(*) = @numreq` no final da segunda *query*

### Leitura complementar:

> [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/6448?s=1|0.0000#6448)

Answer (score 2):

Segue uma solução que atende ao seu problema. A lógica foi simples:

1- Retorno os funcionários que não bateram a meta em um ou mais requisitos.

```
select f.nome, c.requisito, c.valor VALOR_NECESSARIO, p.valor VALOR_ALCANCADO
  from funcionario f inner join cargo c ON f.cargo = c.cod_cargo
  INNER JOIN pontuacao p ON c.requisito = p.requisito AND c.cod_cargo = f.cargo
  WHERE p.cod_funcionario = f.cod_funcionario
                       and p.requisito = c.requisito
                       and p.valor < c.valor ;
```

Retorno :

```
+------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| nome | requisito | VALOR_NECESSARIO | VALOR_ALCANCADO |
+------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| JOAO |         2 |               48 |              34 |
+------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Ou seja, João não alcançou o valor necessário no requisito 2.

2- Agora, faço uma nova consulta que traga todos os funcionários com exceção dos que retornaram na consulta anterior (ou seja, virão apenas os que bateram todas as metas).

```
  select f.cod_funcionario COD_FUNC, f.nome NOME, p.valor VALOR_ALCANCADO
    from funcionario f INNER JOIN pontuacao p ON p.cod_funcionario = f.cod_funcionario
   where f.cod_funcionario not in (
select  f.cod_funcionario
  from funcionario f inner join cargo c ON f.cargo = c.cod_cargo
  INNER JOIN pontuacao p ON c.requisito = p.requisito AND c.cod_cargo = f.cargo
  WHERE p.cod_funcionario = f.cod_funcionario
                       and p.requisito = c.requisito
                       and p.valor < c.valor);
```

Retorno:

```
+----------+------+-----------------+
| COD_FUNC | NOME | VALOR_ALCANCADO |
+----------+------+-----------------+
|        1 | JOSE |              67 |
|        1 | JOSE |              56 |
|        1 | JOSE |              76 |
+----------+------+-----------------+
```